# MongoMapper and Joint Plugin giving issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems, mongomapper

I am using mongo_mapper (0.10.1, 0.9.2) and joint (0.6.0, 0.4) in Ruby 1.9.2 and when ever I try to add the "plugin Joint" to one of my models I get an error. Specifically:

```
ArgumentError: Plugins must extend ActiveSupport::Concern
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongo_mapper 0.10.1/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins.rb:11:in `plugin'
```

I added joint to my gem file and I am just having a hard time pinning down this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with dependency issues in that version of Joint. The remedy to the problem was to require the gem from the git to get the latest version which had a dependcy fix for mongomapper 0.10.1 because the other Joint only supported up through 0.9.x

```
gem 'joint', :git => "git://github.com/jnunemaker/joint.git"
```